# FORM ACTION does not go to wanted method in servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get info from the html form from my servlet.
My problem is I cant get to wanted method by click() method on my servlet.
my servlet is on package login and its name loginServlet.
If you can tell my what wrong with my code :

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
                                        "Transitional//EN\">\n" +
                "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD><TITLE>login</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY>\n" +
                "<FORM ACTION=login/loginServlet METHOD=click>"+
                "<table border ='1'>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<th colspan='2'>Register Account Information</th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Requested Username:</td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' name='username' /></td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Password:</td>" +
                "<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<th colspan='2'><input type='Submit' value='Submit'>"+
                "</tr>" +
                "</table>"+
                "</FORM></BODY></HTML>");
  }
  public void click(){
      int i=0;
      for (i=0;i<1000;i++){

      }
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are way off...

the attribute METHOD is for a GET (method called is the servlet's doGet()) or POST request (method called is the servlet's doPost()), not for any specific servlet's method.

So, accordingly, write your code in the respective method.

Comment: and how can i run the onclick method?

Comment: just delegate the call to that method from within doGet or doPost

Answer (score 3):

As a start, never ever use servlets to spit out static html like that.  Never.

After that's been fixed, you need to learn about how web servers work: a servlet, or JSP, produces a chunk of html that gets sent to the browser.  The browser will render it (show on screen) and look for specific instructions.  A `<form>` basically says: let user fill out whatever fields we have in this form and then call the page/service indicated by the `action=` attribute whereby all form fields are given back as variables.

You probably need to study a bit about web programming, a good free resource for Java web tech is [the Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html).  You'll see that JSP technology is being phased out in favor of JSF (that's why I point to version 5 of the tutorial) but I'd definitely suggest you start with JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the [`<form>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/form).

You need to specify a URL that will end up executing your method.
The HTML `method` attribute specifies the HTTP request verb and can be `GET` or `POST`.